# Wix CloseApplication Element Not Working with Bundle.wxs

Tags: wix

The short question is: How to use util:CloseApplication element in a Bundle.wxs file?

Details:
I made it work as desired in Product.wxs file with following syntax but it's not working/executing when used in Bundle file

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="closePowerPoint"
                       Target="POWERPNT.EXE"
                       Description="Please close PowerPoint application to proceed."
                       PromptToContinue="yes"                         
></util:CloseApplication>
```

Am I missing something in bundle file to make it work, or it's not possible/recommended to use it that way?

Any idea or solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CloseApplication` represents a custom action so can therefore be used only in an MSI package.

Comment: Then I wonder why it is OK to use this element in bundle file and no error appears on compile time.

Comment: There's a GitHub issue somewhere to warn or error in that case.